# Row count always prints as -1 while select values from the database using python script

Tags: python, rowcount

I need to print the row count of the cursor while using select query using python.  But it always returns -1 even the select query returns some values.

Code I've tried:

```
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    print(cursor.rowcount)
```

How to print the rowcount of the cursor?

Comment: have you tried len(cursor.fetchAll())

Comment: Are you using sqlite3, if so read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount

Comment: I'm using Sql server @Hari krishnan

Comment: Yaa len is working @CSMaverick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code returns the lenth of the row.

```
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  len(rows)
```

Comment: Cool, that's what I am about to say. Unfortunately my Cursor giving me login timeout error.! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
len( cursor.fetchall())
```

this should do